# Como cargar varios assembly en c# y invocarlos

Tags: c#

¿Cómo puedo cargar varios assembly y utilizarlos? Ya que cuando cargo uno por medio de:

```
var assemblyBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("ReflectionAssemblyLoadTarget.exe");
var loadMethod = typeof(Assembly).GetMethod("Load", new Type[] { typeof(byte[]) });
var newAssembly = loadMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { assemblyBytes });

((Assembly)newAssembly).EntryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[] { args });
```

Lo cargo y llamo pero cuando cargo varios por ejemplo:

```
//Load the bytes as an assembly
Assembly exeAssembly = Assembly.Load(bytes1);

//Execute the assembly
object[] parameters = new object[1];                //Don't know 
 exeAssembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, parameters);

//Load the bytes as an assembly
Assembly exeAssembl = Assembly.Load(bytes2);

//Execute the assembly
object[] parameter = new object[1];                //Don't know 
 exeAssembl.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, parameter);
```

Solo me invoca el primero pero los demás no. Porqué? A que se debe esto? Solo se puede utilizar un assembly por programa es por eso?

Comment: No entiendo lo que preguntas, ¿Te carga el ensamblado? ¿Qué errores obtienes? ¿Te has asegurado de que estás cargando un archivo ejecutable? Hace falta poner los detalles relevantes.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que todos tus esamblados tienen un `EntryPoint`?

Comment: Hola lo que pasa esque cuando cargo dos ensamblados o pongo un ensamblado y luego otro y lo arranco el siguiente nunca se me arranca, he puesto los detalles es decir ensamblado uno, invoko , ensamblado , invoko (solo me invoka el ensamblado uno) espero que se me entienda.

Comment: Claro ambos se arrancan pero solo puedo arrancar uno.

Comment: No se si es algo así lo que estas buscando pero por si te puede servir:
[https://dzone.com/articles/importing-multiple-extension](https://dzone.com/articles/importing-multiple-extension)

Comment: bytes2, tiene EntryPoint?

Comment: los dos tienen.

Comment: Una razón puede ser que estés cargando ensamblados compilados en una arquitectura diferente. Si tu programa principal es 32 o 64 bits, 
 los ensamblados deberían ser igual. Así mismo, si el exe que cargas es del tipo consola, al cerrarlo con X, termina la ejecución de tu prorgama principal pero si termina por su propia cuenta, tu programa principal seguirá corriendo.

Answer (score 1):

Siendo que tus ensamblados que refieres son ejecutables, te sirve la opción de ejecutarlos vía Process.Start ?

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
Process.Start("ruta/ensamblado");
```